# Cannot assign event listener in Shadcn Vue component in Jhipster 8

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, jhipster

Due to company requirements, I need to use Vue 3 and Jhipster 8.0.0 framework. I have successfully installed the Shadcn Vue and display properly but I cannot assign any event listener.

```
<script setup lang="ts">

    import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button'
    import { ref } from 'vue'
    
    const count = ref(0)
    
    function increment() {
        count.value++
    }
</script>

<template>
    <div>
        <div @click="increment">Home</div> <-- working
        <Button @click="increment">Click Me</Button> <-- not working
        <h1>{{ count }}</h1>
    </div>
</template>
```

In case this is Shadcn version problem, I have checked through the Shadcn Vue button component source code as well. I didn't see any difference compared to other YouTube tutorial GitHub repository.

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should pass your function witout @ and use what ever Button gets for click it might be click or onClick or etc

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried and still not working. Totally no idea why it won't work. But I appreciate your reply.

Comment: can you provide more code form button component?